# Worklight 6.0 application using SSL

Tags: ssl, ibm-mobilefirst

Worklight 6.0.0, targeting iPad.

I have a simple demonstration application, no authentication at present. I am demonstrating use of reverse proxy. So I am building my application using the [Build for Remote Server workaround](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21642937) and can see in xcode the correct server specification. I have some adapter calls, but for a particular demo scenario I also want to make an explicit call to

```
WL.Client.connect( ... );
```

If I use an http connection I see a request like this:

```
http://192.168.0.19/MyApp/apps/services/api/Work01/ipad/init
```

and it works just fine. If instead I use an SSL connection, as expected I see this

```
https://192.168.0.19:443/Infrabel01/apps/services/api/Work01/ipad/init
```

And I get the following error.

```
> [ERROR   ] FWLSE0059E: Login into realm 'NullLoginModule' failed. The
> environment 'ipad' supports multiple versions, therefore you must
> request it with a version parameter.. [project Infrabel01] The
> environment 'ipad' supports multiple versions, therefore you must
> request it with a version parameter. [ERROR   ] 
> FWLSE0117E: Error code: 4, error description: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, 
> error message: An Error occurred while performing authentication using loginModule
> NullLoginModule, User Identity Not available. [project Infrabel01]
> [project Infrabel01]
```

That "request it with a version parameter" is intriguing. Is there some extra parameter I need to pass? Or is the overall implication that connecting over SSL requires authentication?

Comment: I have seen similar issues with connect on SSL on 6.0.0, and trying to consistently replicate the issue. Could you try to use WL.Client.init instead of WL.Client.connect if that suits your application? The downside to init is it can only be called once. It is called by default in initOptions.js in a clean worklight app. I have noticed that init worked in my scenario, but not connect (although currently unsure as to why).

Comment: Mike, this is completely reproducible in my environment. I will try WL.Client.init() as you suggest, just for extra info, but I think connect() is the correct API to be using, I certainly don't want to connect on startup. I would like to understand how it could be that the  server is aware of the certificate I'm using in Apache and hence produce that error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I have solved it by using the real IP address of the server in the WL app instead of using localhost:

1. When the emulator is running your app, press the Menu button.
2. Select to change your server URL
3. Remove "localhost" and use the IP address.
4. Accept and try again.

This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your Worklight server or proxy server is enabled SSL with certificate which signed by a trust public CA like Verisign. Worklight not support private CA certificate.

Comment: My topology is device--SSL-->Apache--HTTP-->WlServer. The error message above is coming from the server, which therefore should be unaware of the certificate I've used.  Do you know for sure that using such a certificate will fix the problem?