# Connection issues from certain devices

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Can't connect from device using custom authenticator and ChallengeHandler.

This is from Worklight 6.1.0.2 from an iPod Touch device.  On the worklight server, we see this in the Stack Trace.

```
klight.console.controllers.UsersController from Application javax.ws.rs.core.Application
[10/8/14 15:20:04:170 CDT] 0000001c com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext                    E FWLSE0059E: Login into realm 'NullLoginModule' failed. Invalid gadget request format: /WorkExecution/iphone/my_custom_auth_request_urlnull. Unknown handler path: my_custom_auth_request_url. [project AnywhereWorkManagement]
com.worklight.gadgets.GadgetRuntimeException: Invalid gadget request format: /WorkExecution/iphone/my_custom_auth_request_urlnull. Unknown handler path: my_custom_auth_request_url
    at com.worklight.gadgets.api.GadgetAP
```

Our challenge handler submits our Authentication information using this Javascript call:

```
challengeHandler.submitLoginForm(challengeHandler.getAuthURL(), loginOptions, l
```

Where getAuthURL returns the string "/my_custom_auth_request."

Strangely, other devices using the same application and worklight server are allowed to login successfully.  Another weird datapoint is that if we popup the Worklight Settings panel on this iPod Touch device, and update the Worklight server information, the worklight login then seems to succeed.

Wireshark log from the failed connection:

```
POST /AnywhereWorkManagement/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/iphone/login HTTP/1.1
Host: mobilenext1.tivlab.austin.ibm.com
Accept-Language: en_US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPod touch; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11D257 (367413328)/Worklight/6.1.0.02.20141006-1624
Content-Length: 71
x-wl-platform-version: 6.1.0.02.20141006-1624
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
x-wl-app-version: 7.5.1.1
Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
Connection: keep-alive
x-wl-native-version: 1475155033
x-wl-device-id: 36CDA8F2-F4E9-49D8-8CBB-A250FDC3B8FA
Cookie: WL_PERSISTENT_COOKIE=ac72a920-b614-423d-8347-e4b5c96a4a1b
Origin: file://
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

realm=CustomAuthenticationRealm&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.7606244247872382HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE"
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Close
Date: Fri, 10 Oct 2014 14:32:15 GMT
```

Then after updating the Custom URL to remove the trailing slash, and relogging in, here's the wireshark log from the successful login:

```
POST /AnywhereWorkManagement/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/iphone/query HTTP/1.1
Host: mobilenext1.tivlab.austin.ibm.com
Accept-Language: en_US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPod touch; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11D257 (384405120)/Worklight/6.1.0.02.20141006-1624
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 210
x-wl-platform-version: 6.1.0.02.20141006-1624
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
x-wl-app-version: 7.5.1.1
Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
Connection: keep-alive
x-wl-native-version: 1475155033
x-wl-device-id: 36CDA8F2-F4E9-49D8-8CBB-A250FDC3B8FA
Cookie: WL_PERSISTENT_COOKIE=0983cfc8-8526-48c9-99cb-72659cb934b4; JSESSIONID=0000wSxsNgF79M62_UJTNmXKKYC:2e8ee48e-dec4-4c69-b8b4-ad37f839f1be
Origin: file://
WL-Instance-Id: okur33g93p35c9j7rvpk1r9g5j

adapter=OSLCGenericAdapter&procedure=getProperties&compressResponse&parameters=%5B%7B%22propertyNames%22%3A%5B%22si.auth.type%22%5D%7D%5D&__wl_deviceCtx=Ar1Cjm4_mo9jpBAA&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.33572526928037405HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 93
Date: Fri, 10 Oct 2014 14:43:15 GMT





 /*-secure-
    {"isSuccessful":true,"responseID":"1516","properties":{"si.auth.type":"maximo"}}*/POST /AnywhereWorkManagement/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/iphone/my_custom_auth_request_url HTTP/1.1
    Host: mobilenext1.tivlab.austin.ibm.com
    Accept-Language: en_US
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPod touch; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11D257 (384405120)/Worklight/6.1.0.02.20141006-1624
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    x-wl-app-version: 7.5.1.1
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cookie: WL_PERSISTENT_COOKIE=0983cfc8-8526-48c9-99cb-72659cb934b4; JSESSIONID=0000wSxsNgF79M62_UJTNmXKKYC:2e8ee48e-dec4-4c69-b8b4-ad37f839f1be
    x-wl-device-id: 36CDA8F2-F4E9-49D8-8CBB-A250FDC3B8FA
    Content-Length: 62
    Origin: file://
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

    username=wilson&password=wilson&authType=maximo&langcode=en-USHTTP/1.1 200 OK
    X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
    P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE"
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
    Content-Language: en-US
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Date: Fri, 10 Oct 2014 14:43:15 GMT

    19
    {"authStatus":"complete"}
    0
```

I found this in the server logs to correspond with that 503 error from worklight server (I can reproduce by POSTing the same login URL).  However in our Worklight Console, there is only one version of each application listed for iphone.

```
 [10/10/14 10:37:54:063 CDT] 00000485 com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet               E FWLSE0020E: Ajax request exception: The environment 'iphone' supports multiple versions, therefore you must request it with a version parameter. [project AnywhereWorkManagement]
[10/10/14 10:37:54:066 CDT] 00000485 com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet               E FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error description: INTERNAL_ERROR, error message: FWLSE0069E: An internal error occurred during gadget request  [project AnywhereWorkManagement]The environment 'iphone' supports multiple versions, therefore you must request it with a version parameter., User Identity {wl_authenticityRealm=null, CustomAuthenticationRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=null, wl_antiXSRFRealm=null, wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_anonymousUserRealm=null}. [project AnywhereWorkManagement]
```

Comment: Scott, please mention the Worklight version, as well as its build number.

Comment: Scott, I am also not convinced that this trailing slash is the culprit. That slash is required and added by Worklight during build because after it the URL in fact continues, i.e.: http://domain:10080/servercontext/services/../.../init -- Please generate a Wireshark log of a successful connecting and another from an unsuccessful connection.

Comment: 1) From what and to what, do you change the server URL in the settings screen? 2) the wireshark log, is that of a successful connection or failed connection...

Comment: 1.) from https://<host>/AnywhereWorkManagement/ to https://<host>/AnywhereWorkManagement (no trailing slash) and 2) I've added both logs now. Notice the successful connection wireshark.log, doesn't have an explicit call to the Worklight login URL at all.  Maybe changing the trailing slash forces the worklight login to go through ahead of time or something?

Comment: Which devices fail and which succeed? Such a change should impact all devices, not some.

Comment: It's intermittent for all iOS devices for us, but the iTouch device can reproduce 100% of the time after the initial app install.

Comment: this seems really similar to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589894/worklight-6-0-application-using-ssl  The same workaround even fixes it (where we change the Server Settings)

Comment: The team will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Scott,

The workaround is to remove the trailing slash from the Server URL.

For a permanent fix I suggest that you will open a PMR so that the development team could investigate the issue closely.
When doing so, please provide a reproducible test case because the flow does work fine, but seems to not work in yours, so need to better understand where exactly it fails. Be sure to provide this question in the description.

It could be that you are altering the URL somewhere in your challenge handler?

Comment: I don't think we're changing the url in the challenge handler.  I can see the correct URL in our log before we call the submitLoginForm method.  I think without the successful Worklight login ahead of time, the submitLoginForm fails with that Null in the command line.